# Centos 7 Serial Port Permissions in VMWare Player

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, serial-port

Ok, what am i missing.

TLDR; I've done all I'm supposed to with permissions, lock directory, compiling, etc of Kermit and I still get the "Sorry, write access to UUCP lockfile directory denied."

VMWare Player running Centos 7 with a comm port defined and connected to another VMWare Player running Centos 7. Connected using named pipe.

Here are all (ask if you need something else) of the details:

```
[jmorrison@djangodvlp ~]$ kermit
C-Kermit 9.0.302 OPEN SOURCE:, 20 Aug 2011, for Linux (64-bit)
 Copyright (C) 1985, 2011,
  Trustees of Columbia University in the City of New York.
Type ? or HELP for help.

(/home/jmorrison/) C-Kermit>set port com1
Sorry, write access to UUCP lockfile directory denied.

*************************
HINT (Use SET HINTS OFF to suppress future hints):
Please read the installation instructions file, ckuins.txt,
or the UNIX appendix of the manual, "Using C-Kermit"
or visit http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ckuins.html 
*************************

(/home/jmorrison/) C-Kermit>show comm

Communications Parameters:
 Line: /dev/tty, speed: unknown, mode: remote, modem: generic
 Parity: none, duplex: full, flow: none, handshake: none
 Carrier-watch: auto, close-on-disconnect: off
 Lockfile directory: /usr/spool/kermit
 Typical port device name: /dev/ttyS0

Modem signals unavailable

Type SHOW DIAL to see DIAL-related items.
Type SHOW MODEM to see modem-related items.

(/home/jmorrison/) C-Kermit>show version

Versions:
 C-Kermit 9.0.302 OPEN SOURCE:, 20 Aug 2011
 Numeric: 900302
 Built for:  Linux
 Running on: Linux #1 SMP Thu Dec 18 14:09:13 UTC 2014 3.10.0-123.13.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64
 Patches: (none)
 UNIX Communications support, 9.0.326, 20 August 2011 for Linux
 UNIX File support, 9.0.216, 20 Aug 2011 for Linux
 C-Kermit library, 9.0.052, 29 Jun 2011
 C-Kermit Protocol Module 9.0.160, 16 Oct 2009
 C-Kermit functions, 9.0.233, 3 Jun 2011
 Command package 9.0.168, 12 March 2010
 User Interface 9.0.299, 9 Jun 2011
 Character Set Translation 9.0.044, 2 Jun 2011
 CONNECT Command for UNIX:select(), 9.0.139, 1 Mar 2010
 Dial Command, 9.0.160, 16 Oct 2009
 Script Command, 9.0.032, 16 Oct 2009
 Network support, 9.0.297, 14 Jul 2011
 Telnet support, 9.0.274, 16 Mar 2010
 FTP Client, 9.0.260, 14 Jul 2011

(/home/jmorrison/) C-Kermit>

(/home/jmorrison/) C-Kermit>quit


[jmorrison@djangodvlp ~]$ ll -d /usr/spool/kermit
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root dialout 6 Mar  8 13:34 /usr/spool/kermit



[jmorrison@djangodvlp ~]$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    1.689372] 00:09: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    1.715790] 00:0a: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A



[jmorrison@djangodvlp ~]$ which kermit
/usr/local/bin/kermit


[jmorrison@djangodvlp ~]$ ll /usr/local/bin
total 2304
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root        340 Mar  8 14:52 ckermit.ini
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root dialout 2354406 Mar  8 14:52 kermit
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root         21 Mar  8 14:52 kermit-sshsub -> /usr/local/bin/kermit


[jmorrison@djangodvlp ~]$ id
uid=1000(jmorrison) gid=1000(jmorrison) groups=1000(jmorrison),18(dialout),54(lock) ...

[jmorrison@djangodvlp ~]$ ls -l /dev/ttyS*
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 4, 64 Mar  7 16:37 /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 4, 65 Mar  7 17:08 /dev/ttyS1
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 4, 66 Mar  2 14:23 /dev/ttyS2
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 4, 67 Mar  2 14:23 /dev/ttyS3

[jmorrison@djangodvlp ~]$ uname -a
Linux djangodvlp.ssla 3.10.0-123.13.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Dec 18 14:09:13 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[jmorrison@djangodvlp ~]$
```

What am I missing?

Thanks
John Morrison

Answer (score 0):

Boy is my face red.

Never mind.  The problem was I stopped testing with "set line /dev/ttyS0" and switched to "set port com1".  There is no com1 but I was still getting the same error message.

I turned on debug logging (-d) and looked through the code to follow what was happening.  Then it hit me to try /dev/ttyS0.

Works.

Sorry for the waste of space.

jbm